# boost sockets in 2 threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I'm using boost sockets and boost threads. (Sync sockets). And if i understand correctly this scheme isn't working.

```
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket *MySocket;
bool Key = true;

void Function1()
{
    try
    {
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
        boost::system::error_code error;
        boost::asio::ip::address address = boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(IP, error);
        tcp::endpoint ep(address, 1235);
        MySocket = new tcp::socket(io_service);
        MySocket->connect(ep);
        Key = false;
    }
    catch(std::exception e)
    {
        std::cout<<e.what;
    }
}

void Function2()
{
    boost::array <char, 8> buf;
    size_t len = MySocket->read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf), error);
    //Always len == 0 and buf.data() is MMMMMMM
}

void main()
{
    boost::thread Thread(&Function1);
    while(Key);
    Function2();
    MySocket->close();
}
```

Comment: I think the simple answer is **Read the documentation**. It's very well documented and it even has examples.  This is NOT how it's done.  Also you are dereferencing a NULL pointer, which is Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: i dont understand. You think that MySocket is NULL pointer? In function1() I'm initializing and opening this socket. It was connected to port in another program. Why in Function2() it's not work? I read documentation for boost::asio, but I dont understand this. Used to write in c#, I dont have this problem. C++ is given heavier than c# :(

Comment: Your code for Function1 isn't descriptive enough. Where do you create the instance of the socket? Supply your implementation and we might be able to give you a clue as to what went wrong

Comment: Added my code for function1.

Comment: Also the way you are using `Key` is really bad and will lead to problems. Try it with a [condition variable](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref).

Comment: And, finally `void main` is non-standard. `main` returns `int`, period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create your socket with *local* `io_service`, which get destroyed after `function1` returns. Make it global. (And of course, do not design real applications this way! Stick with approaches desribed in Asio documentation.)

Comment: I know this, but I just wanted to get it right. Thanks for GLOBAL io_service.